# summation of score - mean doesnt work

Tags: javascript

I tried making mean deviation calculator using javascript but when I try to output the summation of `|x-x̅|`, It always returns 0;

```js
var frequencies = []
var output = document.getElementById("text")

function add() {
  var score = document.getElementById("lol").value
  frequencies.push(score)

}

function show() {
  //Calculate the mean
  var total = 0
  var mean = 0
  var scoreMinusMean = []
  var summation = 0
  for (i = 0; i < frequencies.length; i++) {
    total += parseInt(frequencies[i])
  }
  mean = total / frequencies.length
  //Gets the score - mean
  for (j = 0; j < frequencies.length; j++) {
    scoreMinusMean.push(Math.abs(frequencies[j] - mean))
  }
  for (k = 0; k < scoreMinusMean; k++) {
    summation += scoreMinusMean[k]
  }
  output.innerHTML = scoreMinusMean
}
```

```html
<input id="lol">
<button onclick="add()">Add</button>
<button onclick="show()">Show</button>

Output: <span id="text"></span>
```

Comment: Where are you calling this `add` function?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/ZGJFXnwh

Comment: It's (probably) not the problem, but beware [The Horror of Implicit Globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). Declare `i`, `j`, and `k`. *(Disclosure: That's a post on my anemic little blog.)*

Comment: @jlallas384 - To add a *live example*, please use Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button), not off-site resources. [Here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha).

Comment: You don't "output the summation". You output the array `scoreMinusMean`.

Comment: stackoverflow say to me to add more description because its too many code and I dont know what description to add

Comment: See [mcve], but @Federico already did it for you.

Comment: Add less code. See what I did when I added a snippet in your question. You don't need the whole page, just a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: still doesnt work on outputting summation

Comment: @jlallas384 I didn't fix your code, I just made it runnable. Answering is what answers are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your last loop, the condition you have is `k < scoreMinusMean`, you forgot to add `.length` there. It should be

```
for (k = 0; k < scoreMinusMean.length; k++) {  
    summation += scoreMinusMean[k]
}
```

Also, you should use `let` before declaring the variables or else they will be made global.

```js
var frequencies = [];
var output = document.getElementById("text")

function add() {
  var score = document.getElementById("lol").value
  frequencies.push(score)

}

function show() {
  //Calculate the mean
  var total = 0
  var mean = 0
  var scoreMinusMean = []
  var summation = 0
  for (i = 0; i < frequencies.length; i++) {
    total += parseInt(frequencies[i])
  }
  mean = total / frequencies.length
  //Gets the score - mean
  for (j = 0; j < frequencies.length; j++) {
    scoreMinusMean.push(Math.abs(frequencies[j] - mean))
  }
  for (k = 0; k < scoreMinusMean.length; k++) {  
    summation += scoreMinusMean[k]
  }
  output.innerHTML = summation
}
```

```html
<input id="lol">
<button onclick="add()">Add</button>
<button onclick="show()">Show</button>

Output: <span id="text"></span>
```

Comment: Globals are dangerous -> `k ` Engage good practices! 
And Go ES6 :D

Comment: @CristianS. correct.. and even I have mentioned in my answer.. :)

Answer (score 0):

THe last four lines of your code should be:

```
 for (k = 0; k < scoreMinusMean.length; k++) {
    summation += scoreMinusMean[k]
  }
  output.innerHTML =summation/frequencies.length
}
```

As you forgot the .length on the array, and for a standard deviation, you need to average the deviation again (ie. divide the total of deviations from the mean, by the number of elements).